# CreateJS/EaselJS web page (not game) consisting of several pages

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I have coded an existing (pure) HTML5 Canvas web page consisting of several pages, 'buttons' and 'hotspots'. It is pure canvas javascript code.

Reason why I put 'buttons' and 'hotspots' in quotes is because I have actually implemented those in pure javascript from scratch without using any framework, just created 'classes' for buttons, hotspots, mouse event detection, etc.

These elements are approaching end of its functionality, so I need better elements and especially a scrollbar which will respond well to mouse scrolling.

As web site is redesigned and a lot more new and complex requests are needed to be implemented, it is no more feasible to continue coding in javascript as such, i.e. I need a serious graphical framework.

Between KineticJS and CreateJS/EaselJS I chose the latter.

Now, since this is not an one-page game, but several page long website with somewhat complex navigation relation between pages, can someone advise me what approach should I take? 
Containers, just 'pages' with 'buttons' on it, what should be taken for a button, how to handle different pages and machine states in CreateJS/EaselJS?

Did I made the right choice? Is this easier in KineticJS?

Can you share an experience and/or advice, please?

Answer (score 0):

Since EaselJS is "just" a graphical framework, there is no native support for states. However compared to KineticJS I wouldn't say that there is a huge difference for you purpose (someone correct me if I'm wrong here)

I'd use the same approach of using Containers as Pages. For buttons I'd use the `ButtonHelper`-class: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/ButtonHelper.html

You probably knew most of that already, but I thought I'd still share it, maybe it does help you.

Comment: Yes it does help. I need opinions and other experiences. Thanks!